# font-size in colorbox inside psmallmatrix

Tags: color, fontsize, mathtools, colorbox

I use `\colorbox` to highlight stuff with a background color. In normal text, this works great. I stumbled over an inconsistency of font-sizes when using `\colorbox` combined with `psmallmatrix` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize Text in scriptsize; \colorbox{blue!20}{colorbox works fine}.

\normalsize Text normal; psmallmatrix works fine: $\begin{psmallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{psmallmatrix}$.

\huge Text in huge size, but in the formula small and huge are mixed: $\begin{psmallmatrix} a & \colorbox{blue!20}{\ensuremath{b}}\end{psmallmatrix}$.
\end{document}
```

When I try to highlight something within a `psmallmatrix-environment`, the font size from outside the math-environment seems to be used as opposed to the smaller size from `psmallmatrix`.

Maybe `\ensuremath` is to blame here? If so, is there another way to have colored backgrounds for parts of formulas?

If not: Is there an elegant workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `\colorbox` “forgets” being called in smaller size. You need `\mathpalette`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colormathbox}[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
    \mathpalette\color@mathbox{{#2}{#3}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\color@mathbox}[2]{%
  \color@@mathbox#1#2%
}
\newcommand{\color@@mathbox}[3]{%
  \colorbox{#2}{$#1\m@th#3$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$X\colormathbox[\mathrel]{blue!20}{<}Y$

$X<Y$

\scriptsize Text in scriptsize; \colorbox{blue!20}{colorbox works fine}.

\normalsize Text normal; psmallmatrix works fine: 
$\begin{psmallmatrix}a&\colormathbox{blue!20}{b}\\c&d\end{psmallmatrix}$
$\begin{psmallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{psmallmatrix}$.

\huge Text in huge size, but in the formula small and huge are mixed: 
$\begin{psmallmatrix} a & \colormathbox{blue!20}{b}\\c&d\end{psmallmatrix}$
$\begin{psmallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{psmallmatrix}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good also your answer. +1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand every detail; probably because I don't know enough about TeX's internals. From what I understand, the optional parameter can be used to fine-tune spacing within formulas, as you've demonstrated with `\mathrel`. The other parameters work the same as the two arguments of `\colorbox`. Is that right? Anyway, I have tried it in my document and it solves the problem very well from what I can tell.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Yes, the idea for the optional argument is allowing to restore (manually) the type of the symbol. It could be done almost automatically, but probably it’s not worth the trouble. The two mandatory arguments are the same as for `\colorbox`, but no color model is allowed and the second argument is assumed in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a work-around:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{psmallmatrix}{\everymath{\scriptstyle}}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize Text in scriptsize; \colorbox{blue!20}{colorbox works fine}.

\normalsize Text normal; psmallmatrix works fine: $\begin{psmallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{psmallmatrix}$.

\huge Text in huge size, but in the formula small and huge are mixed: $\begin{psmallmatrix} a & \colorbox{blue!20}{\ensuremath{b}}\end{psmallmatrix}$. %*

\end{document}
```

[image]